# Can anyone point me to some linux file system unit testing libraries?

Tags: c, linux, fuse

I'm not sure how to look for these. I am trying to find general unit testing libraries for linux file systems (FS structure is treated as anon).

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not aware of any such tests existing, so you'll probably have to write them yourself. Please post here if you find anything or if you make something you're able and willing to publish/share.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found unit tests at these locations

http://lwn.net/Articles/276617/

http://www.tuxera.com/community/posix-test-suite/

and this answer talking about performance tests: https://serverfault.com/questions/19487/how-to-do-filesystem-testing

Comment: phew, just remembered to check mark your response when I got home. It really helped me out!

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider trying out a few benchmarking tools.  While they are not unit tests per-se they will certainly stress test a file system, which may be a useful form of testing.

I've used IOZone in the past to good effect (http://www.iozone.org/).

Answer (score 0):

See also http://oss.sgi.com/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=xfs/cmds/xfstests.git;a=summary